# android kitkat webview hides video full screen button when playing video

Tags: android, html, video, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

In my application , i want to load a video in full screen using webview , 
and i follwed this tutorial -  http://shashikaonline.com/2013/06/25/play-html5-video-on-android-webview/_SCREEN_PARAMS

Every thing works fine on android 4.1.2 or 4.2.2 , but in Kitakat (4.4.2) , full screen button disappears when video is playing.I wanted the full screen button to be displayed ehen the the video is playing in kitkat webview.

if any one knows the solution pls share with me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the very same problem as you did almost a year ago. Assuming you found another way in the meantime I propose this answer mainly for future readers.

You can force the fullscreen button to be visible with the help of CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: inline !important;
  }
```

You may also style other video player control elements as written [here](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334).